# С++ или Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++

Здравствуйте. Недавно я начал поверхностное изучение JS. Здесь я задал вопрос о нем, но мне сказали, что лучше заняться С++. Скажите, что практичнее, легче, даёт больше возможностей? Насколько я знаю, JS не требует ничего, а С++ требует компилятор. Если не сложно, посоветуйте вместе с аргументами и ссылками. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: УжОс :) Не стоит нагружать себя С++ если ты хочешь тупо строить сайтики про поездки в египет %) Или для себя...С++ Компилируемый язык требуються компиляторы и разные примочки. Может я в этом плохо шарю но для тебя лучше на JS сидеть...Пока что...Когда дойдёт время и ты подумаешь что тебе мало JS не на словах (В рассуждение чего он может а чего нет) - Воооот тогдааа...Переходи на другие языки...

Comment: я не хочу тупо строить сайтики про поездку в Египет. Я хочу связать с этим свою жизнь, а также и карьеру. Но мне нужно начать с чего-то. Гораздо больше меня привлекает веб дизайн, поэтому изначально я настроен на JS.

Comment: Если хочешь стать профессиональным программистом, учи математику и теорию алгоритмов. А языки невебные все равно придется учить.

Comment: @vendetta8247 Если ты задал вопрос и тебе не понравилось как тебя на него ответели...То уж извени...Разбирайся тогда сам...

Comment: @Fatahan А где ты увидел, что я не доволеН? :)

Comment: @Vendetta8247, когда были IE и netscape - выбор JS казался бы адекватным. Сейчас (спасибо опенсорсу, хромам, операм, сафарям) - вы охренеете, простите, подстраиваться под баги той или иной версии того или иного браузера. Серверный JS - говорят, хорошая вещь, но не с браузерного начинать. Поберегите нервы и здоровье, клавиатуры и мониторы)  Либо сразу начинайте с jquery - знать будете поменьше, но это можно как раз другим языком компенсировать. Но реально живее будете)

Comment: Лучше начни с PHP(Си подобный язык) проще будет переходить на ++ и он веб язык(более или менее)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, странное противопоставление... Это два разных языка, созданных для совершенно разных целей и имеющие совершенно разное предназначение. Если Вы только начинаете изучать программирование, то лучше, конечно, начать не с JS, поскольку это довольно узконаправленный язык. Лучше С++ или даже С, поскольку он проще и короче. Это языки общего назначения,  JS в основном используется для веб-программирования. Применение его для других целей экзотика.

Для С/С++ нужен компилятор. Какой лучше выбрать здесь уже обсуждалось неоднократно. Но повторюсь. Для начинающий лучше, на мой взгляд, среда разработки Dev-C++. Простенькая, бесплатная, но довольно мощная. Использует компилятор gcc.

Comment: А скажите, JS реально настолько сложный, что самому не освоить? Просто некоторые люди так говорили. Просто меня интересует именно веб

Comment: Я в нем не очень большой спец, но то, что я просматривал, мне показалось очень элементарным. По крайней мере, на поверхности. Там большие проблемы с совместимостью с разными браузерами, но это уже другой уровень работы. Основа языка довольно простая.

Comment: Вообще, из своего жизненного опыта скажу, самостоятельно я точно никогда не смогу освоить китайский язык. И вождение автомобиля. Все остальное можно освоить самостоятельно. Ну, или почти самостоятельно.

Comment: ну если не задумываться о кроссплатформенности и не выкладывать в паблик, а чисто для себя, то проблем наверное не будет? Спасибо за совет. Будем читать...

Comment: если интересует веб, то выбор очевиден - js + html, а потом уже можно и язык программирования учить.

Comment: к слову (не по теме), как раз думал о занятиях китайским :)

Comment: Что значит, не выкладываться в паблик? JS язык веб-программирования. Как тут без паблик? Это я могу писать на С всякие свои расчетные программы и не думать о том, как они выглядят, а JS по определению паблик.

Кстати, JS идет в паре HTML.

И не забываем ставить галочки добрым людям, оказавшим помощь.

Comment: это значит, что пишу конкретно для своего хрома плагин, который будет правильно работать только в хроме. То есть я не думаю о том, как он будет смотреться у моего друга на Мозилле.

Comment: @Vendetta8247 Ну если ты хочешь чтоб у тебя на сайте только для хром выводилось какое то действие - то это называеться Идиотизм :DDDD ...JS это клиентский язык и поэтому каждый браузер будет его по разному выводить...

Answer (score 3):

Аргументы? Сложно даже представить, с чего начать. Думаю, начинать вам надо с целей. Они имеют совершенно разные, почти непересекающиеся применения. Определитесь, чего вы хотите для начала.

C++ несомненно хорош для обучения программированию, так как даёт возможность понять, как работает компьютер и как работают программы. Пощупать алгоритмы и т.п. В этом смысле, JavaScript плохо подходит. Вероятнее всего, если вы будете с него начинать, то если у вас нет больших талантов и/или сильной целеустремлённости, то ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет.

Comment: > C++ несомненно хорош для обучения программированию

Вы хотели сказать C?

Comment: Both.......

Comment: Не хочу себя переоценивать, но мне кажется, что такое у меня есть (целеустремленность). Целей на самом деле у меня несколько. Меня привлекает создание различных тематических сайтов, интересно делать что-то, что облегчит веб сёрфинг. А ещё интересно очень было бы написать интересную какую-нибудь программку на андроид. В мечтах создание крутых софтин или даже игростроение (имею опыт работы с 3Д моделями и фш, правда небольшой).

Comment: @vendetta8247 УжОс 2x :D <br><br>
ВладимирВГ да ты гений :)

Comment: @Fatahan Всмысле? Не нравятся мои стремления? Тут уж я решил, что хочу этого. А какими целями буду добиваться - определяюсь сейчас.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m я прям заулыбался с последнего предложения) `if (a) then if (!b || !c) then good = false`, почти дословно)

Comment: Чёрт.. мне пора в отпуск :D

Answer (score 2):

[[@vendetta8247](/users/4217/vendetta8247)](/users/4217/vendetta8247) Внимание альтернативный вариант для тебя! Учи Java а не JavaScript :) - Он и в веб чуть фурычит и в играх его используют (MinеCraft Forever) и для телефонов и во всяких Андроидах он работает(Если учесть для телефонов половина приложений на нём и написано) - Тем более что по статистике он один из самых используемых(Хотя показатель уже  по чуть чуть падает) - поэтому и востребованый. Так что Java тебе в руку(И клавиатуру в другую) :) .

Comment: Уже думал над этим... Достаточно интересно. Спасибо, почитаю про него. Может, начну освоение!

Answer (score 2):

Цитирую : "Эффективность программиста при работе с незнакомым языком программирования снижается в среднем на 20%". Язык не имеет значения. Программист выбирает язык исходя из поставленных перед ним задач. Нужно учиться программировать, а не учить язык - это еще старый добрый дядя Страуструп говорил.

Answer (score 0):

JS программа работает на стороне клиента (браузера). Без взаимодействия с программой на сервере она (по большей части) бессмысленна. Серверная программа может быть написана на C++ (C, PHP, Perl, Python, Java и т.д.).

Кстати, если вы только начинаете программирование, почему бы не посмотреть на **Python** ? Отличный язык (правда не знаю как он в качестве первого). Кроме того на нем (и на Java) можно писать как серверную, так и клиентскую части web-приложения. И в android их можно использовать.

О компиляторе Вы зря беспокоитесь, все это качается абсолютно бесплатно.

Успехов.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я о компиляторе не беспокоюсь, скорее просто интересно!

Answer (score 0):

Учи Java! Я сам начинал с VB, потом прочно "увяз" в Delphi. В универе пришлось заняться C++, потом поюзал C#. А теперь считаю, что совершил ошибку - надо было изначально заниматься Java, которая пригодна для многих сфер. Тем более это самый рейтинговый язык.

Answer (score 0):

ээ. как бы сказать-JS есть язык для веб-программирования.
если ты тяготеешь к этому, то тебе JS и PHP-лучший вариант.
но если ты хочешь также и программировать научится, то учи С/С++. больше узнаешь, большие возможности. JS больше(а скорей в основном) для написания сайтов, но перейти от одного к другому, я думаю, огромного труда не составит.
ЗЫ я сам начинал с JS, но взорвал себе моск..

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то, почти 10 лет назад я тоже задавал себе этот вопрос, но особо всерьез не размышлял над выбором, так как мне казалось, его кроссплатформенность решает, но если производить какие либо манипуляции с файлами, тогда у с++ конкурентов нет. Но имхо все, что можно было написать для работы с файловой системой уже написано.
JS однозначно!